# Blueprint for managing children processes from the parent process in Linux?

Tags: linux, process, fork, parent-child

I need to write an overseer process responsible for forking and managing number of children processes in Linux.

The parent process (overseer) is responsible for:

- starting and stopping children processes (workers)
- restarting them in case of problems
- keeping the configured number of children alive

I'm looking for a proven skeleton / tutorial on how to do it *right*.

(I do understand processes, threads and Linux signals, but I'm far from expert in that regard and seek for the best practices to avoid troubles).

Comment: Perhaps look at how Apache is doing it.

Comment: @larsmans: I'm going to write it in Ruby but example skeleton code is welcome in any language. What matters for me is the structure, signal handling, etc.

Comment: @n.m.: hopefully I'll find a shorter example :-)

Comment: @qertoip: I was asking because there might be library support in your language for handling this kind of thing. In Python for example, you would use the `multiprocessing` or `subprocess` modules for handling this kind of thing. You might want to google for "Ruby process control" and either use or study the libraries you find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long research I have found a nice and simple implementation in the Preforker gem: https://github.com/dcadenas/preforker (Ruby).

Preforker provides exactly what I need.